# Jacoco Code Coverage report shows 0% coverage but Test report shows correct data for Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

I have been using Jacoco for code coverage report generation and was working fine. My project contains Unit test using JUnit5. I'm using "**de.mannodermaus.android**" plugin's for writing tests in JUnit5.

Recently i updated below dependencies -

**App's Build.gradle file** -

```
apply from: '../jacoco-config.gradle' 
apply plugin: "de.mannodermaus.android-junit5"

androidTestImplementation "de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-core:1.3.0"
androidTestRuntimeOnly "de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-runner:1.3.0"
// (Required) Writing and executing Unit Tests on the JUnit Platform
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2"
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2"

// (Optional) If you need "Parameterized Tests"
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.2"

// (Optional) If you also have JUnit 4-based tests
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.8.2"

testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
```

**Project Level Build.gradle file** -

```
 classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.8"
   
 classpath "de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.8.2.1"
```

I have created a gradle file for applying Jacoco changes and setup. The file has below main contents.

**jacoco-config.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

tasks.withType(Test) {
jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']}

jacoco {
toolVersion = "0.8.8"
reportsDir = file("$buildDir/JacocoReport")}

android {
buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }
}
testOptions {
    animationsDisabled true
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
        returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
}
project.afterEvaluate {
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {

    testDebugUnitTest {
        ignoreFailures true
    }
}

def androidExclusion = [
        '**/BR.*',
        '**/R.*',
        '**/R$*.*',
        '**/BuildConfig.*',
        '**/Manifest*.*',
        '**/databinding/*.*'
]

// Create coverage task ex: 'jacocoTestReport<Flavor>' depending on
task "jacocoTestReport"(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the testDebugUnitTest build."

    def javaClasses = fileTree(
            dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug",
            excludes: androidExclusion)
    def kotlinClasses = fileTree(
            dir: "${project.buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug",
            excludes: androidExclusion)
    classDirectories.from = files([ kotlinClasses , javaClasses])
    def coverageSourceDirs = ["src/main/java"]
    getAdditionalSourceDirs().setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))
    getSourceDirectories().setFrom(files(coverageSourceDirs))
    getExecutionData().setFrom(fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ["**/*.exec", "**/*.ec"]))

    reports {
        xml.required = true
        html.required = true
    }
}
}
```

1. When running the Jacoco gradle task, code coverage report shows 0% coverage. [image]
2. However, the test results report is correct and shows the Success and Failed test respectively.[image]

I have checked the jacoco gradle file for the source and destination paths which are correct. Also, the classes file path for Java and Kotlin seems to be correct.

I'm using **gradle plugin version 7.2.2** and **distributionUrl 7.3.3**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote an article long time ago about how to use jacoco with android https://github.com/uriel-frankel/android-code-coverage i hope it will help

Comment: @UrielFrankel - Thanks for your answer. My setup was working perfectly before upgrading the gradle plugin and Unit testing libraries. I wonder if there's anything i might be missing which is required in the updated plugin version. Even the report generated is not excluding the classes mentioned in exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

`testCoverageEnabled false` should solve the instrumentation error issues in your tests if they are passed with exception
here's the detailed answer: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178015739#:~:text=go...%40gmail.com%3E-,%232,-Jan%2022%2C%202021](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178015739#:%7E:text=go...%40gmail.com%3E-,%232,-Jan%2022%2C%202021)

Answer (score 0):

I've commented the list of androidExclusion:

```
def androidExclusion = [
    '**/BR.*',
    '**/R.*',
    '**/R$*.*',
    '**/BuildConfig.*',
    '**/Manifest*.*',
    '**/databinding/*.*'
]
```

and the coverage is no longer 0.

EDIT: `testCoverageEnabled` must be `false`!